# If @@ROWCOUNT is 0 stored procedure

Tags: t-sql

I have the following code in my stored procedure, which executes upon user input on an HTML page.

```
SELECT  a.code, a.name
FROM    table2 b
        INNER JOIN table1 a ON a.id = b.id
WHERE   b.data = @parameter
        AND b.condition = 1
        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0

    SELECT  a.code, a.name
    FROM    table2_archive b
            INNER JOIN table1 a ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE   b.data = @parameter
            AND b.condition = 1
```

I want to check, if an entry exists in the current table and if not, it should go check in the archives and return that.
However, when the procedure is called, it returns both tables, so if there is no data in the current table, the user will get an error, since both tables are returned, but I only want it to return one. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've wrong understanding of `@@ROWCOUNT` usage, yes it

> [returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

but it doesn't prevent execution of previous query.

If you want to use `@@ROWCOUNT` then previous statement shouldn't have a output result (e.g. it can be `update`, `insert`), and your query can looks like this

```
--varchar(100) -- because you don't specified the data types

DECLARE @parameter AS VARCHAR(100) = 'xxxx'

DECLARE @tbl1 AS TABLE (code VARCHAR(100), name VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tbl1 (code, name) -- last statement
SELECT  a.code, a.name
FROM    table2 b
        INNER JOIN table1 a ON a.id = b.id
WHERE   b.data = @parameter
        AND b.condition = 1

-----------------------------------
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 -- check if last statement are not produced the rows
--also `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @tbl1)` can be used here, to check if @tbl1 contains a records
    BEGIN
         SELECT  a.code, a.name
         FROM    table2_archive b
                 INNER JOIN table1 a ON a.id = b.id
         WHERE   b.data = @parameter
                 AND b.condition = 1        
    END
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM @tbl1
```

Comment: This could be rewritten to perform the first query with a result into `@tbl1` and then either return that as the result _or_ query the archive and return the result. There is no need to query the archive or store the result in a table variable if the first query has returned the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If the `@@ROWCOUNT` is `0`, the stored procedure will return two result sets - the first one will be empty and the second one might have rows.

You need re-write the query to produce a single result set no matter if it was selected from `table2` or `table2_archive`.

One way to do it, assuming no duplicated rows in `table2` and `table2_archive` is to use a common table expression and `union all` like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  data, id
    FROM    table2 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  data, id
    FROM    table2_archive 
)

SELECT  a.code, a.name
FROM    cte b
        INNER JOIN table1 a ON a.id = b.id
WHERE   b.data = @parameter
        AND b.condition = 1
```

If there are duplicated rows, a slightly more cumbersome solution can be applied:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  a.code, a.name
    FROM    table2 b
            INNER JOIN table1 a ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE   b.data = @parameter
            AND b.condition = 1
)

SELECT code, name
FROM CTE
UNION ALL

SELECT  a.code, a.name
FROM    table2_archive b
        INNER JOIN table1 a ON a.id = b.id
WHERE   b.data = @parameter
        AND b.condition = 1
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM CTE
        )
```

Comment: I currently "solved" my problem by declaring a new variable and making it save the count value of the active table; if it's 0, it checks the archives. This has me executing the same SELECT statement twice though. Not sure which is better, your solution or mine.

Comment: @EInherjar anyway you will need to execute two statements to determine more suitable in case when you need to get a chose between, so you can only use `execution plan` to get those query which produce smallest execution time (just a performance case)

Comment: @zohar you solution will return output from both queries in case when each of them will have outputs

Comment: @Vasily the first solution, yes, the second will only produce output from one table.

Comment: @ZoharPeled but OP needs only the second in case when the first doesn't produce output result, but your algorithm will produce both in case both are exist

Comment: @Vasily I've explicitly written in my answer that the first solution is assuming no duplicated rows in `table2` and `table2_archive`. The second query will only return values from `table2_archive` if they do not exist in `table2`.